# Relations in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, grouping, nodes, relation

Hi Im new to neo4j and I have a little database that describes the reviews of a movie.

Basically, the nodes are set like this:

```
(Critic)-[review]->(Movie)
```

The review relation has an attribute called stars which describe the stars given by the critic to the movie.

An example is this.

```
(Jon)-[review{stars:4}]->(Titanic)
(Jon)-[review{stars:3}]->(Avatar)
(Alf)-[review{stars:4}]->(Avatar)
```

I have an excersice that Ive been asked to get all the critics that have given 4 star in their reviews but never gave an 3.

The answer in this case must be Alf

Any idea of how I can make the MATCH in cypher?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j as not a function that is call group. But you can aggregate your values like SQL

```
MATCH (n { name: <group lable> })-[r]->() RETURN type(r), count(*)
```

for a single group.

```
 MATCH (n)-[r]->() RETURN type(r), count(*)
```

for all groups 
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/

Comment: Thanks Denis i al ready tried used but my problem is how I aggregate son I can match that condition